# Flutter - How to calculate Size of a Widget before rendering?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget

I'm trying to make a responsive UI that consists of 2 main elements - Video Player and its Controls.

The controls do have a dynamic height and I need to calculate remaining height on top of the Controls Container which is going to be used for the Video Player (MediaQuerry [height of display] minus height of the Controls).

Is there a way to calculate this before rendering of the screen? Ive alredy tried Offstage but Im getting null on the Controls size.

I'm expecting a solution which will tell me how to calculate remaining free space before rendering the whole page.

Comment: I dont think that it can be used in this situation since the both Video and Controls widgets are in a Stack with Controls being on top.

Comment: so instead of `Stack` use `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: Ive looked into it, but Im not really sure how to use it in order to calculate the sizes

Comment: [layoutChild](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/layoutChild.html) returns child's size - the docs say: "Ask the child to update its layout within the limits specified by the constraints parameter. The child's size is returned."

Answer (score 0):

My go-to for this kind of peer-sensitive layout is [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy). You can write relatively arbitrary code that can "size" anything with a layout pass, and use that to locate other dependent items.  There are also prewritten solutions for common difficult layouts like dominant-widget-sized rows.

Comment: Not sure how would I go about this. Since I need to firstly render the bottom controls sheet and then fill the remaining space with video player.